# Context Menu Fails To Remove A File Item From A ListView Row

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

My contextmenu Fails to Remove a File Item from a ListView Row.
My code runs and the Toast indicate the methods are working.
There are not any logcat errors. My ListView is working correctly.

**My Question is:** What is wrong with my code?
Please provide the correct code to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Java Code: class TestActivity

```
    public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

                    private String root;
                    private List<String> item = null;
                    private ListView listview;

                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

                        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

                        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/ListTestFiles";
                        getDir(root);

// 01-Nov-2017 For reference added 6 lines of my existing Java code.
listview = getListView();
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
File file = new File(path.get(position));
String fullPath = new String(path.get(position));

                        } // End of onCreate code.


                    // 02-Nov-2017 For reference added 28 lines of my existing Java code.
                    private void getDir(String dirPath)
                    {
                        currentPath = dirPath;
                        item = new ArrayList<String>();
                        path = new ArrayList<String>();

                        File f = new File(dirPath);
                        File[] files = f.listFiles();

                        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
                        {
                            item.add(root);
                            path.add(root);
                            item.add("../");
                            path.add(f.getParent());
                        }

                        for(i2=0; i2 < files.length; i2++)
                        {
                            File file = files[i2];

                            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()){
                                path.add(file.getPath());
                                if(file.isDirectory()) {
                                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                           }else {
                                    item.add(file.getName());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_item_view, R.id.rowtext, item);
                        setListAdapter(fileList);

                    } // End of getDir method


                     @Override
                     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                                     ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                         super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                             MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                             inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
                     }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.context_menu_rename:
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Rename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return true;

                            case R.id.context_menu_delete:

                                // TEST #1 the line of code below runs but will Not delete the selected listview row item.
                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TouchActivity.this, R.layout.layout_item_view, R.id.rowtext);

                                // TEST #2 the line of code below runs but will Not delete the selected listview row item.
                                // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TouchActivity.this, R.layout.layout_item_view);

// 01-Nov-2017 Added 2 New lines of code.
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.remove(String.valueOf(info.position));

// 01-Nov-2017 Commented out 2 lines of code.
// String index = valueOf(info.position);
// adapter.remove(index);

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position = " + info.position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Toast.makeText(this, "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                return true;
                            default:
                                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

XML Code: layout_item_view.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#231f20">

            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rowtext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

XML Code: row.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/rowtext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

XML Code: activity_test.xml

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#231f20">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@android:id/list"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:fillViewport="true" />
                </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat output:

```
// Test 3 I run the app with this code.
case R.id.context_menu_delete:
                fileList.remove(fileList.getItem(info.position));
                fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

// Test 4 I run the app with String.valueOf code because the adapter is an ArrayAdapter<String>
case R.id.context_menu_delete:
                fileList.remove(String.valueOf(fileList.getItem(info.position)));
                fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

// Logcat output is the same for both Test 3 and 4, the app crashes with the error below.

    --------- beginning of crash
11-03 17:40:02.840  18362-18362/com.testing.listapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testing.listapp, PID: 18362
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.testing.listapp.TestActivity.onContextItemSelected(TestActivity.java:5413)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2905)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4701)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1082)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you instantiate a brand new adapter, do not pass any data to it, do not set it as the ListView's adapter. So nothing much *can* happen. - If you need more help with fixing your code, please post more of it (e.g. how do you initialise the ListView in the first place?)

Comment: @ 0X0nosugar For reference I added more lines of my existing Java code. I also added code for 'listview.setAdapter(adapter)' and adapter.remove(String.valueOf(info.position));. Now when I do a long press on a Row item of the ListView, 
then press Delete on the context menu, all ListView Rows are removed from the view. I restart the activity and the ListView is shown with all rows still present. Nothing was permanently removed. How can I permanently remove the item selected from the Row of the ListView?

Comment: @0X0nosugar For reference added 28 lines of my existing Java code showing how I initialize the ListView with the original adapter.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I made the original ListView adapter a global field of the Activity with code: 
private ArrayAdapter<String> fileList; I added the Logcat output and testing notes. 

I don't understand the use of 'item' in this comment: 
"If you want to be absolutely certain that you delete the correct entry then you have to make your data list a field and remove the entry at index info.position by calling item.remove(info.position) "

Comment: The NullPointerException most likely occurred because you still write `ArrayAdapter<String> fileList  = ...` inside of `getDir()`. This would mean  you're declaring and initialising a local variable with the same name and so the field *fileList* stays `null`. If this is the case, simply omit "ArrayAdapter<String>" inside the method.

Comment: About the meaning of *item* in `item.remove(info.position);`: I'm trying to use the variable names from your code. *item* ist the List<String> which you create and pass as data list to the adpater in `getDir()`. When I'm talking about the data list in the same sentence, I am also referring to *item*

Comment: @0X0nosugar For reference, my ListView is a list of Audio files, each of which can be several MB in size. 

As you suggested, inside the method getDir(), I removed "ArrayAdapter<String>", this fixed the nullpointer error. 

Now when I do a long press on a Row item of the ListView, then press Delete on the context menu, the selected Row item is removed from the view. But the audio file associated with the Row item has not been removed from storage.

I restart the activity and the ListView is shown with all rows still present. Nothing was permanently removed.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I verified that the audio file is still in storage using the Astro file manager app. To make efficient use of storage space, when a file is no longer needed I need to remove it from the ListView and storage to free storage space. 

How can both the Row item and the audio file be permanently removed at the same time?

Comment: Well, your question was not about deleting files. It was about implementing a context menu and manipulating a data list associated to a ListView adapter. I answered your question. My solution works because you now manage to make one row disappear while still showing all the other rows, mission accomplished. So accept my answer if you feel that it helped you to get one step further and maybe ask a new question - and don't forget: Google is your friend ;-)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I agree that I am one step closer to solving the problem. 
But in my description of the problem that I am seeking help with I did mention "My contextmenu Fails to Remove a File Item from a ListView Row", please see my post. The row has been removed but the File has not been removed.

Comment: Well, I think maybe the question title is ambiguous. I understood that you wished to "remove something from some place where it can be found initally" like "remove a list entry from its list". But one can also understand that you wish to "remove something (no matter where it actually is) which is represented by/ identifiable by the content of a ListView row".Given your problems with the context menu/ the adapter I think my interpretation was not totally wrong. You definitely needed help there.(cont)

Comment: (cont) If you also need help with deleting a file, then you have two questions. The "How to delete..." question has been asked and answered before, but the rules for accessing files have changed over the years. I'd suggest you read (and try the code snippets from) the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#DeleteFile) or try googling "android delete File", and if that doesn't work, you'd best ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now when I do a long press on a Row item of the ListView, then press Delete on the context menu, all ListView Rows are removed from the view.

Let's take a look at some lines in `onContextItemSelected()`:

The following line gives you a brand new `ArrayAdapter`. Its `getCount()` will return 0 because you did not pass any data list to it:

```
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TouchActivity.this, R.layout.layout_item_view, R.id.rowtext);`
```

Now you set this "empty" adapter as the `ListView` adapter:

`listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

The old adapter will be discarded. The current one has an empty data list. So now the `ListView` is empty.

Because the current adapter is "empty", the following line will have no effect:

`adapter.remove(String.valueOf(info.position));`

> I restart the activity and the ListView is shown with all rows still present. Nothing was permanently removed.

That's because you re-initialise the `ListView` with the original adapter.

**EDIT**

How to delete the selected item?

The first thing you need to do is make the original `ListView` adapter a field of the `Activity` or `Fragment` hosting the `ListView`:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> fileList;
```

Then you instantiate it and set it as adapter for the `ListView` after you have initialised your data list, e.g. at the end of `getDir()`:

```
//...
fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_item_view, R.id.rowtext, item);
setListAdapter(fileList);
```

The data will be shown like before. And now you can access this adapter all over your `Activity`, for example in `onContextItemSelected()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.context_menu_rename:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.context_menu_delete:
            fileList.remove(fileList.getItem(info.position));
            fileList.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```

Note that `fileList.getItem(info.position)` must be a unique value because under the hood `ArrayAdapter#remove()` means `List#remove()`, so the first matching  `List` entry will be removed, never mind its index. If you want to be absolutely certain that you delete the correct entry then you have to make your data list a field and remove the entry at index info.position by calling `item.remove(info.position)`

And how to make the changes permanent?

What we have achieved now is that the user can delete one entry from the data list, and the `ListView` will reflect this by no longer showing the deleted entry. The `ListView`/ adapter will preserve their state if you leave the app and return to it after a short while, e.g. by pressing the "HOME" button.

But if you tilt the device and so cause an orientation change (from portrait to landscape and vice versa), then `onCreate()` will be executed and the deleted data will be back. The same is true if the user presses "BACK" and then taps on the launcher icon.

So if you want to make changes permanent you have to persist them somehow. (But I think this is beyond the scope of this question.) See for example the guide on [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: For reference added 28 lines of my existing Java code showing how I initialize the ListView with the original adapter.